# Check If date exceeds 24Hrs from start date in moment

Tags: javascript

Check If date exceeds 24Hrs from start date in moment.

```
Ex: 
   My date string **"27-05-2021 10:26:29 PM"**. I want to check from this start date exceeds or not.  I'm using moment.js
```

Comment: Can you tell how you get date, is it Date type or just a string, also can you get it in the format of timestamp?

Comment: @ ilyas Jumadurdyew , this is my issue. That's why i'll ask here. I just get the stored date value from db..

Comment: What DB you are using, and what framework you are using (django, flask, node, laravel)? Database is storing date-time in db date type format, unless you have stored datetime as a string for char_field which is worst practice ever

Answer (score 2):

You can use moment js `format` and `diff` function.

```
let a = moment("27-05-2021 10:26:29 PM", "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss A");
let b = moment();//todays date in local time zone
console.log(a.diff(b, "hours"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use diff and duration

```js
var x = moment('27-05-2021 10:26:29 PM', ['DD-MM-YYYY HH:NN:SS']);
var y = new moment()
var duration = moment.duration(x.diff(y)).as('hours');

console.log(duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to parse string to get a valid date.
If you will use moment(dateString) directly, invalid date will be the result:

```
const dateString = '27-05-2021 10:26:29 PM';
const startDate = moment(dateString); // invalid date
```

so:

```
// parse string using format string to get a valid date
const dateString = '27-05-2021 10:26:29 PM';
const startDate = moment(dateString, 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss a');

// finally get the difference from other date in hours/minutes/years
const today = moment(); //to get todays date
const hoursDiff = today.diff(startDate, 'hours'); //diff in hours
const minutesDiff = today.diff(startDate, 'minutes'); //diff in minutes
```